# VirtualBox menu bar missing on OSX host and Windows 10 guest

Tags: virtualbox

I've looked through every post I can find but none solves my problem.

**What I've tried:**

1.Editing VirtualBox.xml adding while VirtualBox is not running:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Toolbar" value="true"/>
```

2. Settings -> User Interface (I can control the status bar and the menu bar options, but there is no option to show/hide the menu bar)
3. Right-clicking the status bar and select show menu bar (No such option exists when I try)
4. Through the top "MacOS menu" selected View -> Menu Bar -> Show Menu Bar (No such option exists when I try, I can only edit the menu bar options here)

Please, I'm soon losing my mind. How can I show the Menu Bar?

Comment: Are you running fullscreen? Does it not appear if you just hold the cursor to the top of the screen?

Comment: It does not appear when holding my cursor at the top of the screen unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried toggling fullscreen mode, see what happens?

Comment: I've tried toggling both using command + f and command + c. This hides and shows my Status Bar so I can see thats working. However the Menu Bar is nowhere to be seen

Comment: Fullscreen toggle is cmd/ctrl/F. Cmd/f is find & cmd/c is copy, unless VB is stealing some very generic global shortcuts, in which case, I've no idea.